# How to add a comma after the list field in Gravity form

Tags: forms, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I want to add a comma after the field in Gravity form. I'm using a list field and after submitting the form there should be a comma after each name.

live form :- https://docs.ajsrp.com/t1

see the attached image
https://i.ibb.co/HNVzZsS/Web-capture-26-3-2022-13560-docs-ajsrp-com.jpg

I want to add a comma after the field in Gravity form. I'm using a list field and after submitting the form there should be a comma after each name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to get an array of names separated by commas you may just want to add a new hidden field to your form that can be updated by the list of names after submission. Try adding this code to your functions.php

```
add_action( 'gform_after_submission_1', 'array_name_list', 10, 2 );//1 in this case is your form id
function array_name_list($entry, $form ){
    $list=unserialize( rgar( $entry, '4' ) );//4 in this case is the listfield 
    $entry['20'] = implode(",",$list);//replace 20 with new hidden field id
    return GFAPI::update_entry( $entry );
}
```